# The contents of last column in a DataGridView gets squeezed instead of the just moving

Tags: c#, datagridview, autosize, datagridviewcolumn

I have a DataGridView with 5 columns. And the last column has AutoSizeMode set to 'Fill'. And, now when I am resizing say , I expand the second last column header towards right, a scrollbar appears but the contents in the last column are shrinking and the text starts displaying dots.

Is there is a way I can avoid the contents from getting squeezed? Is there is a way to make the last column just move towards right rather than squeezing contents (by enabling scrollbar) when I'm expanding the second last column?

I have set the AutoSizeMode to Fill only for the last column as I need that column to fill the grid.

Before expanding:

[image: Before expanding]

After expanding:

[image: After expanding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to set the `MinimumWidth` property of the last column.

Comment: The solution worked. I wonder why didn't it strike to me :) Thanks!